# Midori crashes randomly and often in 14.04

Tags: skype, crash, midori

This is getting worse by the day....clicking on a link does not work, but right-clicking 'open in new tab' works! Sometimes after opening the page, the screen dims, and Midori crashes...Seems to happen more often these days... the last one came up with message that 'your system does not have enough memory to report the problem to developers'.

Other than mail I don't leave any application running, usually.

Except Skype which I started leaving it on..the past few days....I don't know if Skype is messing up ...

Comment: Give it up, midori is just r crashy. Try new opera or maxthon if you want something different. You can also try to report bugs and be patient.

Comment: @forstjiri thanks. But I don't see Opera or Maxthon in SW center?!

Comment: It's not in repost yet, you have to download deb package http://www.opera.com/download/get/?partner=www&opsys=Linux&product=Opera%20beta&utm_medium=sm&utm_source=desktop_blog&utm_campaign=beta www.maxthon.com/blog/tag/linux/

Comment: @forstjiri  thanks much! Installed Maxthon, and it looks and works great.

Comment: Please provide a backtrace of crash to psream

Answer (score -1):

Do not maximize midori. It crashes in this mode. With a small window it won't crash.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi Melvin...I will try this. I believe flash plugin is misbehaving and that might be the source of this problem...Even Maxthon gets sluggish after a certain time after browsing. People have complained about Chrome as well..it might be a good idea to fix the flash compatibility to 14.04..

Comment: Yes, smaller window seems to help. However, if one fiddles with the size of the window to get better page visibility it still crashes. I checked the agent option, and it is set to 'automatic'. I don't know if changing it to Firefox, IE or something else will help..